# Exposing an endpoint as a sub of another endpoint?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service, DummyService. It implements IDummyService and lives on two URIs, http://1.1.1.1/DummyService and http://2.2.2.2/DummyService. I would like to create a routing endpoint such that;

1. I can hit http://1.1.1.1/RoutingService/DummyService?wsdl and/or http://1.1.1.1/RoutingService/DummyService
2. This uri appears to just be the dummyservice endpoint, i can build a client proxy, etc.
3. Any calls get round-robined around

Is there some way to do this without having IRoutingService re-implement DummyService? I want dummyservice to essentially be a plug-in that I can add/remove at runtime.. Can I do this with WCF Routing? Any samples I can reference? I havent been able to find anything on MSDN/Google, but perhaps im asking the wrong way..

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much exactly what WCF Routing is for.

There is a sample which is part of the WCF/WF samples (info here):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667249%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: I looked at this, but im not clear how this would handle relaying? Really what Im after is to create a route under my service that literally impersonates the backing server.. In azure this is a relay binding, but without azure, no idea..